# Mongoid only working in development. Throws error both is test and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

When I start my rails console as:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=development rails console
```

every thing seems to be working fine. 
Mongoid is able to connect to mongodb and fetch records.

But with:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test rails console 
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails console
```

it's throwing up errors as:

```
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.16/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:585:in `check_for_missing_documents!':  (Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound)
Problem:
  Document(s) not found for class Actor with id(s) 50e5259f53c205d815000001.
Summary:
  When calling Actor.find with an id or array of ids, each parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be raised. The search was for the id(s): 50e5259f53c205d815000001 ... (1 total) and the following ids were not found: 50e5259f53c205d815000001.
Resolution:
  Search for an id that is in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned instead of raising this error when searching for a single id, or only the matched documents when searching for multiples.
```

My config/mongoid.yml has the exact same set of lines for all three environments.
I'm not able to figure out why it isn't able to connect in test and production.

**Update:**
Mongoid.yml

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: tgmd
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: tgmd
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGO_URL'] %>
```

I temporarily solved the issue by placing a:

```
options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
```

in production:
Also moved out a few scripts from jobs/ folder. It worked then.
Can anyone enlighten me on this?

Comment: can you post your "config/mongoid.yml" + Gemfile. And try to create your db. "rake db:drop rake db:create"

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but doens't the error say that you're trying to fetch a document that's not in the database? It's not a configuration problem imo.

Comment: Ya that is true. But the code was requesting for non-existent documents was a script on jobs/ folder. I did not suspect that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your ENV['MONGO_URL']  contains something that is not correct.
Try to use your development database in production:

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: tgmd
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
```

if it work. Check your ENV['MONGO_URL']